# When moving to new domain, should old page redirects be implemented on the the old or new domain?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect

I am moving our website to new more appropriate domain name.  Our current domain has a number of 301 redirects from a former naming structure that we changed a few years back.  And we want to maintain those redirects because there are still news and blog articles that reference the old urls.

Is it better to leave the old 301s in place on the current domain and add new redirects for the current pages to their counterparts on the new domain.

Is it better to redirect everything to the new domain and recreate to old redirects on the new domain.

Or something that might be more appropriate than either of the above.

In the for what it is worth department, both domains are hosted on the same server, same IP address.

Comment: Six of one... I would make all redirects as simple as possible and avoid redirect chains, however, if you are just talking about two in a chain, then... half a dozen of another!

Comment: It is usually easier to implement the redirects on the new domain because you don't have to change as much.    Old style URLs would then work both on the old and new domains.    On the other hand implementing it on the old domain would decrease the number of redirect hops needed to resolve the old URLs.

Comment: How about leaving the old website up, and canonicalize all the pages to their respective new domain urls

Comment: @titico - Is there an advantage to using canonical with an essentially mirrored website versus redirecting everything to a single new domain.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - Is there any advantage of one or the other in terms of not losing search engine ranking.

Comment: @Tom it depends, the only advantage here is that you will be avoiding 301 redirects chains. But if you decide to keep the old website I will suggest arranging most of its content to meet the needs of users up in the conversion funnel, this way you can keep old urls with backlinks with canonical to the new website.